# 'MongoError: pool is draining, new operations prohibited' when trying to switch databases

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to access my `prod_clone` database and then disconnect that database and then access my `development` database.

But I getting `MongoError: pool is draining, new operations prohibited` when I try to grab data from the second database database.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const User = require('../models/User.Model');

(async () => {
// first database
  mongoose.connect(process.env.PROD_CLONE_DB_DSN);
  const user = await User.findOne({ email: 'myemail@gmail.com' });
  mongoose.disconnect();

// 2nd database
  mongoose.connect(process.env.DEVELOPMENT_DB_DSN);
  const user2 = await User.findOne({ email: 'myemail@gmail.com' });
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -----------throws MongoError-----------

  mongoose.disconnect();


})();
```

How can I switch to my second database without throwing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [`connect`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-connect) and [`disconnect`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-disconnect) returns a `Promise`, try to `await` them:

```
(async () => {
  try {
    // first database
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.PROD_CLONE_DB_DSN);
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: 'myemail@gmail.com' });
    await mongoose.disconnect();

    // 2nd database
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.DEVELOPMENT_DB_DSN);
    const user2 = await User.findOne({ email: 'myemail@gmail.com' });
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -----------throws MongoError-----------

    await mongoose.disconnect();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Makes sense. It's just so weird I was always able to connect without awaiting and I was always wondering why that call wasn't async. I guess it was async but mongo just connected fast enough some how before my code called the database.